# How to locate thread 1 exc bad exception error - finding light switch in a dark room

Tags: objective-c, multithreading, macos

OK, in a general sense, this suggests a UI (main thread) usage of a junk variable either by miscount retainCount or uninitialized, but how to find where?

In my case I have an app window with several tabs, each of which nib loads a view. Recently when one of these selected, and the view/nib is loaded I get this:
[image: Stack view]

this model had been working for years.  What's new? Xcode 8, a weather module used by items in the view where the failure occurs.  I've littered breaks everywhere but I'm trying to see a stack which apparently this isn't detailed enough. Does the stack show a "description" was sent to a bogus object?
[image: NSApplication stack]

Comment: Could you share your view's called methods (like viewDidLoad:, init, awakeFromNib, etc)? Or a part of the code where UTF8String is called on explicitly if there is?

Comment: UTF8String is in a call path from within the XMLDictionary module - the "tell" was the "\n" which I found uniquely there. I'm coming at this from the standpoint of what's new and focusing on that. Of course there might be some skeletons but the issue only happens in this one view with the dictionary changes; perhaps it exposed something?  What I'm seeking is an approach to trap this error so I can investigate further.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The screenshot you posted shows "_crashOnException:" in the stacktrace.

That indicates that an exception was tossed.  Let the program crash without the exception breakpoint active, and it should log information about the exact exception being thrown.

Comment: WOW; I had no idea what you were talking about but got me to thinking maybe I could *add* such a breakpoint - I didn't have any AFAIK - on exception and viola - you can add such from Debug -> Breakpoints -> Create Breakpoint Exception...; So I added one and now with a locale to triage I can resolve this! The locale is in an embedded object within the view being loaded.  Awesome, thank you.